# HTML Select control does not have selected value when generated with Razor DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view in asp.net/mvc4/razor application where I want to edit value of model using dropdownlist control. I use it this way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DateFormat, new SelectList(new [] {"mm/dd/yyyy", "dd/mm/yyyy"}))
```

The value of DateFormat property is set to one of those values in model but when I load the view, the html select is always set to first value. Am i missing sth?

UPDATE:

This was driving me nuts for two days. Finally I changed the name of property and it started to work. I think it somehow conflicted with value I stored in ViewData/ViewBag collection under the same key. I am not yet sure why. Maybe somebody can explain that?

Comment: Can't see any problem, working for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try your `SelectList` something like this where you define the text and the value, along with the selected item.

```
@(Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DateFormat, new SelectList
(
    new List<Object> {
        new {
            value = "mm/dd/yyyy", text = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        },
        new {
            value = "dd/mm/yyyy", text = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        }
    }, "value", "text", Model.DateFormat)
))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is untested

Make the `SelectList` a buddy property of the model.

```
public class MyModel(){
    prop DateTime MyDate {get;set;};
    prop SelectList SelectDates {get;set;}
}
```

Then populate the `SelectList` after you have selected your date (remember to do this every time you build your model):

```
    SelectDates = dates.Select(d => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = d.ToString(),
        Text = d.ToString(),
        Selected = d == MyDate
    })
```

Then use the property when you build your dropdown:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DateFormat, Model.SelectDates ))
```